# How to access instances in the Availability Zone which is Down.?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat, availability-zone

There are two Availability  Zone in a VPC, I would like to access instances which are in one Availability Zone when the other availability zones is down. Doesn't matter Private or Public instances.

Comment: Need more description.  exactly what you are planning to achieve with which AWS services?

Comment: This is what im practicing right now, correct me if im wrong! So, I've created a VPC and Launched instances in 2 different availability zones. My Question is when one of the availability zone is down will i able to still access the instances which are in that AZ. and how?

Comment: Can we access the instances using NAT gateway?

Comment: No, you won't be able to log in on instance which are in the down az.

Comment: Lets take AZ1 is down & AZ2 is Up. Now can i use the instances which are in AZ1 thru AZ2 ? Or is there any other way to access them

Comment: No you can not access it & there is no way to access it.

Comment: Great Thank YOu!

Answer (score 1):

If an availability zone is 'down' you will not be able to (reliably at least) access any of the resources in it - An AZ is essentially an entire data centre in one geographic location, so it being down means that something is going pretty wrong (eg security incident, earthquake, power outage etc).